# MessageBox variable

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a variable and assign it a message box.

Example:

```
MessageBox nomatch =  MessageBox.Show("No such thing", "Warning");
```

Is this possible in c# windows forms?

Comment: why do you need that ?

Comment: Most things are possible in c#.  Perhaps you mean _"This this possible in WinForms?"_ or _"This this possible in WPF?"_?   One exists in WinForms and is quite extensive

Comment: When i make a search and the input doesn't found a match, this message box appears... And i need to use it for multiple exceptions

Comment: @MickyD - Windows forms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When i make a search and the input doesn't found a match, this message box appears... And i need to use it for multiple exceptions

`MessageBox` doesn't have any public constructor so you can't create it and assign to a variable. But if you want to execute same code in different place, you can declare a `Func` delegate like this:

```
Func<DialogResult> showMsgBox = () => MessageBox.Show("No such thing", "Warning");
```

And call it wherever you want to show message box:

```
showMsgBox();
```

If you don't care about return value you can use `Action` instead.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments, I think this is what you may want.

```
private static void ShowMessageBox(){
    MessageBox.Show("No such thing", "Warning");
}
```

when you need the messagebox, just use

`ShowMessageBox()`

you can also extend the method to

```
private static void ShowMessageBox(string msg){
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Warning");
}
```

show you can input the message you want with `ShowMessageBox("Hello World!")`

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot create a new instance of the MessageBox class.**

Look into the remarks section of below MSDN documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx

More over `show` returns `DialogResult`, which is enum type.